# Python check if any element in a list is a key in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**What would be the Pythonic way to check if ANY element in a list is a key in a dictionary?**

Example, I have a list of fruits:

```
fruits = ['apples', 'bananas', 'pears']
```

And want to check if ANY fruit is a key in my dictionary, examples:

```
fruit_dict1 = {'apples': 4, 'oranges': 3, 'dragonfruit': 4} returns True

fruit_dict2 = {'oranges': 3, 'dragonfruit': 9, 'pineapples': 4} returns False
```

So far I have:

```
def fruit_checker(list, dict):
    for fruit in list:
        if fruit in dict:
            return True
    return False
```

It feels weird to just look for a fruit "in" a dictionary, but it seems "in" only does a search on dictionary keys.  **How exactly does "in" work with the different types?**

Comment: Why does it feel weird to use `in` with dictionaries if it does exactly what you wish?

Comment: To answer your question: see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__.  Briefly, if your object defines `__contains__`, `__iter__`, or `__getitem__`, then `in` operator should work.  It is up to the implementation to do something sensible.  For `dict`, `__contains__` returns True if the value passed is in the keys.

Comment: The keys of the dictionary are a sequence; all the same techniques in the linked duplicate apply.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this

```
In [1]: any([i in fruit_dict1 for i in fruits])
Out[1]: True
In [2]: any([i in fruit_dict2 for i in fruits])
Out[2]: False
```

**Working**

```
In [11]: [i in fruit_dict2 for i in fruits]
Out[11]: [False, False, False]
```

Which check the every element present. And return a list of boolean values and `any` will return if any `True` is exist.

```
In [13]: any([True,False,False])
Out[13]: True
```

Comment: In your first solution you don't need to create the extra lists. You can `any(fruit in fruit_dict for i in fruits)`. You also don't need `keys()`, the `in` operator does that by default. With the list comprehension and `keys()` you are creating 2 extra lists. Trivial here, but could be costly in other situations.

Comment: @RahulKP, IanAuld is right, please accept my edits without the keys() method and I will make this the accepted answer

Comment: @devonJS Updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Let's define your variables:

```
>>> fruits = ['apples', 'bananas', 'pears']
>>> fruit_dict1 = {'apples': 4, 'oranges': 3, 'dragonfruit': 4}
>>> fruit_dict2 = {'oranges': 3, 'dragonfruit': 9, 'pineapples': 4}
```

Now, let's test for membership:

```
>>> bool(set(fruits).intersection(fruit_dict1))
True
>>> bool(set(fruits).intersection(fruit_dict2))
False
```

#### How it works

`set(fruits)` is the set of fruits.  We want to find if there is any overlap between this set and the set of keys of your dictionaries.  To find what the overlap is, we can use the *intersection* method:

```
>>> set(fruits).intersection(fruit_dict1)
set(['apples'])
```

To convert this to True for a non-empty intersection or False for an empty one, we use *bool*:

```
>>> bool(set(fruits).intersection(fruit_dict1))
True
```

#### Minor variation

The same principles if we reverse the order:

```
>>> bool(set(fruit_dict1).intersection(fruits))
True
>>> bool(set(fruit_dict2).intersection(fruits))
False
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass a generator that iterates over the list to `any`:

```
fruits = ['apples', 'bananas', 'pears']
fruit_dict1 = {'apples': 4, 'oranges': 3, 'dragonfruit': 4}

print(any(list_item in fruit_dict1 for list_item in fruits))
>> True

fruit_dict2 = {'oranges': 3, 'dragonfruit': 9, 'pineapples': 4}

print(any(list_item in fruit_dict2 for list_item in fruits))
>> False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set(fruits) & set(fruit_dict1.keys())
```

or using Counter

```
from collections import Counter
any(Counter(fruits) & Counter(fruit_dict1.keys()))
```